# lstnewenvironment and include

Tags: listings

I have several environments for listings such as:

```
\lstnewenvironment{JavaScript}[1][]  
{  
 \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Code (JavaScript)}  
 \lstset{#1,language=Java}  
}  
{  
}
```

This works perfect but I would like to be able to include the code instead of inserting like the snippet below:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Java, label=myLabel,caption=myCaption]{includes/myFile.js}
```

Edit:

Currently I use:

```
\begin{JavaScript}[caption=example, label=code:Example, style=numbers]  
  alert("hello world");  
\end{JavaScript}
```

I would like to have an external file such as example.js and show it in my PDF. I can do that with:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Java, label=code:Example,caption=example]{includes/example.js}
```

but the `\begin{JavaScript}` will show  "Code (JavaScript) 1.1: Example" instead of "Code 1.1: Example". I want to be able to use the first but link an external file as done in the second :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Sorry but I can't read any question/issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you mean you want to write the Javascript code in your TeX file?

Comment: I edited the post to make it more clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your environment you changed `\lstlistingname` If you want to do the same for your input you can define an own input command:

```
\newcommand\javainput[2][]{%
 \bgroup%
   \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Code (JavaScript)}   
   \lstinputlisting[language=Java,#1]{#2} 
\egroup}
```